# finding points by tangents

Tags: calculus

I solved a question and I got the right answer, but I don't know how it work, and I didn't understand the question.

There is a function: $f(x)=\frac{2x^2+1}{x-2}$

1. find the tangent's slope in the point $(1;-3)$ (this is the part I understood);
2. find points where the tangent makes an angle of $45°$ with the $x$ axis in positive direction.

**(1)** The derivative  is $f'(x)=\frac{2x^2-8x-1}{(x-2)^2}$ .
So I set $x=1$ and got right answer: $-7$.

**(2)** I solved right because I found how to solve question like this in this wonderful site. but I don't understand why.

$\tan(45°)=1$.

I set the derivative to 1 and found $x_1=5$ and $x_2=-1$ , which is the right answer according to the book.

Can someone explain me, please, why this is the solution, and what the question is asking about? I understand nothing of number **(2)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, we have $$f(x)=\frac{2x^2+1}{x-2}\implies f'(x)=\frac{2x^2-8x-1}{(x-2)^2}$$ Since, the tangent makes an angle of $45^\circ$ with positive x-axis hence its slope is $\tan45^\circ=1$

Hence, we have slope of the tangent $f'(x)=1$
$$\implies \frac{2x^2-8x-1}{(x-2)^2}=1$$$$x^2-4x-5=0$$ $$(x+1)(x-5)=0\implies x=-1,\  5$$
The above values of $x$ are the values of the x-coordinates where tangents make $45^\circ$ angle with the positive x-axis.

Now, setting the values of $x=5$ & $x=-1$ in the equation of the given curve, the corresponding of y-coordinates are $y=17$ & $y=-1$

Hence the points of tangency are $(5, 17)$ & $(-1, -1)$ at which the tangents make  an angle of $45^\circ$ with the positive x-axis.